# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2 952.62'

Tags: python, dataframe, format

I have a dataframe with data registered as string.
I tried to get them as floats with `astype` function but it just doesn't work and I am struggling to understand why.

I am getting the following error :

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2 952.62'

My data are either XXX.XX when there are decimals and XXX when there are not.

Comment: Your string appears to have a space in it.

Comment: I thought that was just the display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, where columname is the name of your column:

```
df[columname].str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)
```